# Python: Generic method that can return different object type in Pythonic style?

Tags: python, generics

I want build two tree, the build approach is exactly same, but tree nodes are of different types. I have a implementation but not sure if that is the "Pythonic Style"? Is there any Pythonic style approach?

The method I implement like this:

```
import collections
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

# Use Breadth First approach to build a tree, the input list is LeetCode style list,
# like this: [1,2,3,4,5,null,7]

def build_binary_tree(ints: list[int], root: T) -> T:
    root.val = ints[0]

    def bfs():
        length = len(ints)
        que = collections.deque([root])
        i = 1
        while que:
            if i >= length:
                break
            for _ in range(len(que)):
                node = que.popleft()
                if i < length and ints[i]:
                    node.left = type(root)(ints[i]) #Here get constructor of the parameter "root"
                    que.append(node.left)
                i += 1
                if i < length and ints[i]:
                    node.right = type(root)(ints[i]) #Here get constructor of the parameter "root"
                    que.append(node.right)
                i += 1

    bfs()
    return root

# Here are the usage of the method:

# The node type is "Node"
root = build_binary_tree([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None, 6, 7, None, None, None, None, 8], Node())

# The node type is "TreeNode"
root = build_binary_tree([5, 1, 5, 5, 5, None, 5], TreeNode())
```

Comment: Do you really need to return root if you are passing it as parameter?

Comment: I pass the root as parameter because I need get the node type.

Comment: Since you have a working piece of code, you might be better off asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is specifically for questions of that kind.